# logout from Google+ from other activity

Tags: android, google-play, google-api-client

I have recently implemented the Google+ API. I managed to succesfully authenticated and move forward to the main activity. My issue is that I would like to include a "LogOut" option in the action bar menu and when the user comes back he will be prompted to login again.

I read several answers however I wasnt able to implement them.

can you please suggest the best way to implement this solution and suggest a good example?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to implement something? Where was the problem?

Comment: Yes, tried to use singleton object but i was stuck with implementing all retrieve information once client is connected, tried also to create another googleapi client on the target activity but when i re enable the application it automatically logged in instead of prompting which account to use. I always tries the implementation on my own before reaching here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I manage to solve the issue, i created the below base class and just inherited it over the needed activities, I tested and it worked as expected. to anyone who needs an idea on how to build it you can use the below code.

Two points, on the main login activity you will need to change the flags state according to the on click events.

if you like to logout from G+ account on other activity, make sure to initilize the GoogleApiClient first otherwise you will get null object reference exception.

hope that will help someone...

```
public class BaseClass extends AppCompatActivity  implements 
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Context mContext;

    /* "mIntentInProgress" is A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     * True if we are in the process of resolving a ConnectionResult
     * "mSignInClicked" FLAG is True if the sign-in button was clicked.  When true, we know to resolve all
     * issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
     */

    public boolean mIntentInProgress;
    public boolean mSignInClicked;

    public String mPersonName;
    public String mImageUrl;
    public String mEmailAddress;

    public BaseClass(){

    }



     public void CreateClient(Context mContext){
        //Client builder that return GoogleAPI client, make the connection from the app to the G+ service
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)//add OnConnected and OnConnectionSuspended methods to control the connection state
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) // add OnConnectionFaild listener in case connection was failed.
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)//profile permission from the user
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)// login details from the user
                .build();
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
     }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("google base class", "onConnected invoked");
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                mPersonName= currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                mImageUrl=currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                mEmailAddress = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i("google base class", "onConnectionSuspended invoked");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

        Log.i("google base class", "onConnectionFailed invoked");

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            if (mSignInClicked && result.hasResolution()) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                    // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void onLogout() {

        Log.i("base class", "logout invoked");
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i("base class", "logout invoked");
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }
    }


    /**
     * Revoking access from google
     * */
    public void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                            Log.e("base class", "User access revoked!");
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                        }

                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define GoogleApiClient in a common class, then it can be retrieved by any other class you want

```
public class UserSessionManager implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        // Context
        private Context _context;

        // Google plus Client
        public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        // Constructor
        public UserSessionManager(Context context){
            this._context = context;

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(_context)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this).build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.i("google base class", "onConnected invoked");

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.i("google base class", "onConnectionSuspended invoked");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }


        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

            Log.i("google base class", "onConnectionFailed invoked");

        }
    }
```

Just use your mGoogleApiClient as you usually do, for example:

In LoginActivity...

```
    UserSessionManager session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    private void googleSignIn() {
           Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(session.mGoogleApiClient);
           startActivityForResult(signInIntent, application.TAG_RESULTLOGINGOOGLE);
    }
```

In LogoutActivity

```
      UserSessionManager session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

      private void googleLogOut() {
           Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(session.mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Toast.makeText(_context, "G+ loggedOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

try putting this code in the click of your own button or whatever event you want.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Comment: the logout should be placed inside a different activity, creating an instance of GoogleApiClient will force me to implement all related methods which create more clutter in class, im seeking for a solution in terms of code reuse. I understand that there is an option to use base class and extand it within each class however im not sure how to hanlde on connect events and on failure events within the target class, do you have any suggestions?