# Android code for Google plus signin in one activity and signout from another activity

Tags: android, google-plus, logout, google-signin

I need step by step procedure including some sample android code for Google plus signin in one activity and signout from another activity in android eclipse.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: please Google your question before asking question on SO

Comment: @bpA: I have referred this tutorial on Android hive. But its not having a separate activity for logout. I could'nt find any other examples for google plus login and logout separately. That's why I have asked it here! Please let me know if you have got a solution for this..

Comment: Do you implement login?

Comment: @ bpA: Yeh! I have referred the same code in android hive to implement login. But there, logout is in the same activity as of login. But I need logout in separate activity..

Comment: Refer to my answer in a similar question...
[G+ login/logout from different activities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42166619/3900793)

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for over a week to find out the answer. 
I did this,
After signing in save boolean isSignedIn in sharedpreferences as true.

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.userDetails), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), true);
editor.apply();`
```

Now from any activity when the user clicks logout, change the boolean to false.

Now in your Login Activity where `googleApiClient` is build. In its onStart method.
Check if `isSignedIn` is false.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
if (!prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), false)) {
    signOut();
    }     
}
```

Do the same in `onConnected`

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: " + "yes it is connected");
        if (!prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.isSignedIn), false)) {
            signOut();
        }
    }
}
```

This will logout and revokeAccess.

```
public void signOut() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "signOut: " + mGoogleApiClient + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            // ...
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + mGoogleApiClient);
                        }
                    });
         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResult: Revoke Access status:" + status.getStatus());
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this method for Logout..

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Button mButton = (Button)findviewById(R.id.mButton);
        mButton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                     signOutFromGplus();
                }
            });
}

public void signOutFromGplus() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this one! But can you show me how to add logout button in separate activity ..tha't my issue!

Comment: you can add default button and fire this method in onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

For Logging out google plus you can use application class

for study you can refer these articles

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Then assign you variable in this class (Advantage of using this class is that this class starts when application is launched and you can access this anywhere in app ) as :

Your application class name :

```
public class MyApplication
{
public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

and in your  Login activity class

assign this as variable while sign in

```
/**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication )getApplicationContext();
myApp.mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleApiClient;

            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
```

and in logout activity

```
public void signOutFromGplus() {
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication )getApplicationContext();

    if (myApp.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(myApp.mGoogleApiClient);
        myApp.mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        myApp.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Hope you understand this procedure.

Comment: mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() is giving me null value.